# Avoid text wrapping in apex:pageblocksection in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocksection, pageblocksectionitem

I have used apex:pageBlockSection in my VF Page but the problem is that the text is getting wrapped down.

Below is the code:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Generate Schedule of Investments Report for {! fund.Name}">
   <apex:pageBlockSection id="fields">
      <apex:inputField label="Report as of" value="{! dateContainer.As_Of_Date__c}" required="true" />
      <apex:outputText />
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <br></br>
   <apex:actionRegion >
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
               <apex:inputCheckBox label="Show Unrealized Rounds" value="{!includeUnrealizedRounds}" selected="true"  />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
               <apex:inputCheckBox label="Show Realized Rounds" value="{!includeRealizedRounds}" selected="false"  />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:actionRegion>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

When I inspect the code, the following the `<td>` tags are being added for no reason.

[image]

Below is the UI on how it is being rendered:

[image]

Required output: I don't want the text to be wrapped down and want it to be in a straight line.

Can someone please help me out on the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting an `apex:pageBlockSection` inside an `apex:pageBlockSectionItem`. In other words, Visualforce is doing exactly what you're asking it to. `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` takes up to two components and renders them as the label and data cells for the current `apex:pageBlockSection`. Then, you have another `apex:pageBlockSection`, so the `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` thinks that the entire section is the label, and squeezes it into an itty-bitty space. The solution is to remove all the extra inner elements.

Here's your code cleaned up:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Generate Schedule of Investments Report for {! fund.Name}">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="fields">
        <apex:inputField label="Report as of" value="{! dateContainer.As_Of_Date__c}" required="true" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputCheckBox label="Show Unrealized Rounds" value="{!includeUnrealizedRounds}" selected="true"  />
            <apex:inputCheckBox label="Show Realized Rounds" value="{!includeRealizedRounds}" selected="false"  />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlock>
```